# Automatically slide images on html header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to make this slider automatic while also rotating the images in order on the provided hexagons. Also, the first image should be added to the background then to the hexagons, until it gets back.

How do I do this using JavaScript and CSS?

I am trying to make the slider clean without any arrows but navigation needs to be supported by clicking on the hexagons. If a hexagon is clicked, then the image on the shape is automatically transferred to the background while also automatically switching the remaining shapes to their positions.

```js
$("#hexGrid > ul:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $("#hexGrid > ul:first")
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo("#hexGrid");
}, 3000);
```

```css
#hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  left: 75px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#hexGrid>ul {
  display: flex;
  left: 75px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hex::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
  /* =  100 / tan(60) * 1.5 */
}

.hexIn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  /* =  width / sin(60) */
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hexIn * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hexLink {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}


/*** HEX CONTENT **********************************************************************/

.hex img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}

.hex h1,
.hex p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(45, 87, 47, 0.2);
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.hex h1 {
  bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hex h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hex p {
  top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


/*** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/

.hexLink:hover h1,
.hexLink:focus h1,
.hexLink:hover p,
.hexLink:focus p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/*** HEXAGON SIZING AND EVEN ROW INDENTATION *****************************************************************/

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  /* <- 5-4  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 16.666%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  /* <- 4-3  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 16.666%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  /* <- 3-2  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 16.666%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* <- 2-1  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 50%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #hexGrid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="side-hexagon" id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <div> </div>
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>Agency Banking</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none" font color="black">With over 100 agents Agribank provides the best banking network</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>AgriSave</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>KidSave</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>Shades of Green</h1>
        <p>View</p>
        <data style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque malesuada non
                                            diam non egestas. Etiam vulputate ipsum vel est finibus molestie id eget mauris.</data>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```